# node index.js returning "Unexpected token >"

Tags: node.js, express, syntax-error

I have been doing javascript for a while and decided to start node.js.
 I am running node.js and express on a raspberry pi (but I doubt this is the root of the problem). 
I am making a chat app with socket.io, and the instructions said to create a package.json:

```
{
  "name": "socket-chat-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "my first socket.io app",
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Then I ran the command `npm install express@4`.
After that, I made an `index.js` file.
This is the code.

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Error code:

```
/home/pi/Desktop/index.js:4
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

SyntaxEror: Unexpected token >
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's choking on the arrow function? See if using a normal function works? If it does, you should update the Node version to something much more modern

Comment: I started node.js programming 1 hour ago, could you give me an example? My version of node is 0.10.29

Comment: Oop. Heh, that's definitely the issue

Comment: Oh. Yeah raspberry pi might be the issue after all lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions are an ES2015 feature. Generally, environments after 2015 support arrow functions (and other modern syntax). Node 0.10.29 was released [in 2014](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/).

To fix it, install the latest long-term version that your machine supports: probably 14.6.0. See [here](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Uninstall Node with

```
sudo apt remove nodejs
```

and then install it (which will fetch the latest version)

```
sudo apt install nodejs
```

Comment: I have changed to mac, which is newer.

Comment: Raspberry pi, for whatever reason downloads 0.10.29 maybe because it does not meet the requirements for node 15/14/13/12/11/10/9/8/7/6/5/4/3/2/1/.

Answer (score -1):

As I remember this can be the reason. Just add the "script" property like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
}
```

Also there's not express installed. If this will not work, please show the complete view of package.json